# Abrir ventana de Cuentas disponibles del menú ajustes de android

Tags: java, android, android-settings

¿Cómo se puede abrir directamente la ventana `cuentas` del menú ajustes del sistema de Android?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único referente a la cuentas que he podido observar dentro de `Settings.` ha sido `ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT` su apertura:

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT), 0);`

Pero como indica el código abre la ventana para añadir una cuenta, yo la que quiero es la pantalla previa de añadir la cuenta, es decir a donde se muestran todas las cuentas que están en el sistema. La APP de contactos de Google creo que la abre.

Comment: Hola @Webserveis, como otros módulos de la configuración, me temo que  lo que realizas en realidad es hasta donde puede llegar abrir programaticamente.

Comment: Me he puesto a probar uno por uno por uno, acabo de econtarlo con ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS

Comment: Ups veo querias solo las cuentas disponibles, pensé deseabas entrar a agregar por ejemplo: add account.

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir la ventana de ajustes de sistema en la pantalla Cuentas disponibles

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS), 0);`